# WebDriver: Locating elements with Dynamic Ids embedded in a string

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Could anyone suggest how I can locate the element "ToBeSelected" that has the below html code:

```
<div id="Locate-17-tab-info" class="tab active" data-tab-name="tobeselected"> ToBeSelected </div>
```

The XPath 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[contains(@id, '-tab-info')]")).click();

I did not have success with finding by XPath - starts-with and ends-with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You May try

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//input[contains(@id,'Locate') and text()='ToBeSelected'])).click();
```